# What is the mean curvature of a developable surface?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

I am trying to calculate the mean curvature of a developable surface but having some difficulty. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I am very new to differential geometry so please bear with me, but this is what I have so far:

I have a developable surface given by:

$$ \mathbf{X}\left(u,v\right) = \boldsymbol{\gamma}\left(u\right) + v \mathbf{g}\left(u\right)$$

where  $\boldsymbol{\gamma}$ is a unit-speed curve (directrix) and $ \mathbf{g} $ is a unit vector along the generator. The generators are assumed to be inclined at an angle $\beta\left(u\right)$ with the tangent to the curve $\boldsymbol{\gamma}$.

With First fundamental form: $ Edu^2 + 2F du dv + G dv^2 $ 
and Second fundamental form: $ e du^2 + 2 f du dv + g dv^2 $

I get:
$$ E = \left(\boldsymbol{\gamma}_u + v \mathbf{g}_u\right)^2 = 1 + 2v \sin{\beta} + v^2 $$
$$ F = \left(\boldsymbol{\gamma}_u + v \mathbf{g}_u\right) \cdot \mathbf{g} = \cos{\beta}$$
$$ G = \mathbf{g} \cdot \mathbf{g} = 1 $$
$$ g = f = 0 $$
$$ e = k_N $$
where $\left(\cdot\right)_u = \frac{d\left(\cdot\right)}{du} $ and $\left(\cdot\right)_v = \frac{d\left(\cdot\right)}{dv} $ and the mean curvature is:
$$ H = \frac{eG - 2fF + gE}{2\left(EG-F^2\right)} = \frac{k_n}{2\left(\sin{\beta}+v\right)^2} $$

Which doesn't seem to be correct...

I found a reference for the mean curvature of a ruled surface [here](http://journals.cambridge.org/abstract_S1757748900002449):

$$ H = \frac{k_n-v\left(2 k_n k_g + \tau_g'\right)+v^2\left[k_n \left(k_g^2+\tau_g^2\right)+\left(k_g \tau_g'-\tau_g k_g'\right)\right]}{\left[\left(1-v k_g\right)^2+v^2 \tau_g^2\right]^{\frac{3}{2}}} $$

How is this obtained? And also, how can this be simplified in the case of a developable surface with the generators oriented as described above?

Comment: Could you please explain the following things: 1. You have $k_n$ as well as $k_N$. Are they equals? 2. Is $k_n$ one of the principal curvatures? The other principal curvature is zero, since the Gaussian curvature is zero. 3. Why $|g_u|^2=1$?

Answer (score 0):

In order to seek mean curvature of developable surfaces with $K=0$ using  ruled surfaces that essentially have negative Gauss curvatures $K<0$ ..imho.. is going to be a tough start, may well be not the way to go.

There is no need to go into any of the other curvatures viz., $k_g,\tau_g,\text{other non-principal } ~k_n.$ A lot of computational labor should be saved.

Simply put, the mean curvature $H$ can be found out from scalar curvatures directly. If $k_1,k_2 $ are principal normal curvatures then ***by definition*** the mean curvature anywhere (since $k_1=0$)

$$H=\dfrac{k_1+k_2}{2} =\dfrac{k_2}{2}=\dfrac{1}{2 ~R_2}$$

where $R_2$ is minimum radius of curvature. It applies to all cones, cylinders and developable helicoids of vanishing Gauss curvature.

In graphical depiction the mean curvature is a (red) dot in Mohr's Circle diagram being the circle center. The vector arrow end-point shows the circle locus of all normal curvatures versus geodesic torsions as you rotate a normal plane ( containing $N,B$)  around the normal vector $N$ ( rotation of the green line ) as axis.

$$ k_n(\psi)=k_1 \cos^2 \psi+k_2 \sin^2 \psi ~;\text{ Euler's Law}$$

[image]